# what does "predict", "milestone" and "tie into" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

> Some psychologists believe that 'while object permanence alone may not
>   **predict** communicative achievement, object permanence along with several other sensorimotor **milestones**, plays a critical role in,
>   and interacts with, the communicative development of children with
>   severe disabilities'. This was observed in 2006, in a study
>   recognizing where the full mastery of object permanence is one of the
>   milestones that **ties into** a child's ability to engage in mental
>   representation.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_permanence#Recent_studies

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Predict* means to say now what will happen later.

*Milestones* is jargon for "age-appropriate achievements|mastery of function".

*Ties into*  is just a sloppy|casual phrase for "is associated with".